# Is there a WordPress boolean for "theme_customizer_active()"?

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer

Looking to add an action to `wp_head` but only if the user is in "theme customizer" mode.  Does anyone know if there's a conditional for this?

Comment: What does "theme customizer mode" mean? Do you mean if the current user has the capability to edit_theme_options? If so:

`if ( current_user_can('edit_theme_options') ) {
// do your stuff
}`

Comment: Nope, the theme customizer is where a user can adjust certain front-end aspects (e.g. "Link Color", "Background Image", etc.) and see changes in "real time" before committing them.  Here's the full drilldown: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

Comment: It works by showing the user the site "live" as changes are made and shows the latest version in an iframe which can then be "Save & Publish"'d when changes are satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook a function to the `customize_preview_init` action. In that function, do your add_action for the `wp_head`.

The `customize_preview_init` action runs in the call that renders the frame that the preview page is displayed on, and happens early enough to hook onto wp_head.

Comment: Thanks Otto - that's what I was looking for I think.  I've been reading your post on this a fair bit lately :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a hook that fires when you are actually customizing the theme at `wp-admin/customizer.php`, with the tool bar on the left, then [there are several hooks on that page](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/customize.php). For example (but not an exhaustive list)...

```
do_action( 'customize_controls_init' );
// ...
do_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts' );
```

You should be able to narrow things down with the available hooks. I don't know if a `boolean` is set anywhere, such as a constant like `WP_DEBUG`

Comment: Thanks, I think Otto's answer was a bit more specific, though this was helpful as well.